# Go next in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

i have a dgvw and two buttons,one button to go next in dgvw and one to go back! using this code

```
If userdatagrid.CurrentRow.Index < userdatagrid.Rows.Count Then
            userdatagrid.Rows(userdatagrid.SelectedRows(0).Index + 1).Selected = True
```

the problem is, in the DEFAULTCELLSTYLE of the dgvw, the SELECTION BACK COLOR is set to blue .SO, when i click n the button to go to the next row in the datagridview, it works but even the previous row rmains selected . This code doesn't work either :

```
         If userdatagrid.CurrentRow.Index < userdatagrid.Rows.Count Then
            userdatagrid.Rows(userdatagrid.CurrentRow.Index + 1).Selected = True
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You cant use `And` to get 2 statements to execute like that.  Use a If/Then/Else block.  Also, please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: `CurrentRow` and `SelectedRows` are 2 different things.  That code adds rows to the `SelectRows` collection, so of course they are blue/selection color

Comment: so how do i deselect the previous row ?

Comment: if i try this code :

    If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index < DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then
DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1).Selected = True
End If

it only works once i mean it goes to the next row for the first time and then the code wouldn't work or nothing happens